# SQL UNION Query with Extra uncommon Field in Results

Tags: sql, union

I have Four table, Now I display four common field using **UNION** sql query.

**Question** : I want to display one uncommon field ( Company ) which in table name as Multiple Product with current result.How can I do it ?

**Current SQL** :

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Credit Card' AS card_type 
       FROM credit_card 
       UNION 
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Personal Loan' AS card_type 
       FROM personal_loan
       UNION 
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Financial Health' AS card_type
       FROM financial_health
       UNION
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Multiple Product' AS card_type
       FROM multiple_products ) A
```

Comment: Some sample data along with the output you expect would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an empty (or `NULL`) field to the other `SELECT` queries in the space where you want to return the `Company` field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT reference_number,
              name,
              contact_no,
              email,
              create_date,
              'Credit Card' AS card_type,
              '' AS company -- use NULL here if you prefer
       FROM credit_card 
       UNION 
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Personal Loan' , ''
       FROM personal_loan
       UNION 
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Financial Health' , ''
       FROM financial_health
       UNION
       SELECT reference_number,name,contact_no,email,create_date,'Multiple Product' , Company
       FROM multiple_products ) A
```

Note that you only need column aliases on the first `SELECT`.